# expose data to global scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

```
socket.on('connected', function(rand){

      socket.on('draw_'+rand, function(){


      });
    });

//I want to get rand here

function abc(){
}
```

For some reason I can't put function abc within socket.on, so how do I pass rand into function abc? how to expose it to global scope?

Answer (score 0):

```
var rand = null;
socket.on('connected', function(rand_){
  rand = rand_;
  socket.on('draw_'+rand, function(){


  });
});

//I want to get rand here
alert(rand);
function abc(){
}
```

just put in into the global namespace and it should work. Otherwise via constant:

```
rand = null;
socket.on('connected', function(rand_){
  rand = rand_;
  socket.on('draw_'+rand, function(){


  });
});

//I want to get rand here
alert(rand);
function abc(){
}
```

but note: JS is executed async, that means that your `rand` will be alterted as "null" and later it will get its new value from the connected listener.
greetings